# how to fix Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in

Tags: php

how to fix Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in ”

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'xklsvme_blog', 'aP495889%56X');      
mysql_select_db('xklsvme_blog');
$blogid=$_REQUEST['bid']; 
mysql_set_charset($con,'utf8');
```

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_`. Use `mysqli_` or PDO!

Comment: mysql is deprecated and was removed in PHP7 - PHP5.X I think is now end of life .. upgrade your PHP and use PDO or mysqli_* functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch $con and 'utf8':

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

Heads up though, the `mysql_set_charset` is depricated and removed in php7 and your code smells like its vulnerable to sqlinjections